# Delete all the files in a folder and its subfolders without deleting the folder structure

Tags: linux, files, recursive, delete

I am replicating a server -> I want to delete all the files inside the folders and the subfolders, without deleting the directories themselves.

Example:

```
    home\apps\Batches\hello.txt
    home\apps\Batches\test\text.txt
```

Output:

```
    home\apps\Batches\
    home\apps\Batches\test\
```

Only the files should be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\` to separate directory name components is a windows thing.

I would do something like:
`find . -type f -delete`

Note: That command is highly dangerous, be sure you really want to do it, and make sure you're in the correct directory (as I tell `find` to start in `.` the correct directory is the root of the subtree that should be emptied.

Comment: Strictly, you might also need to delete other types like soft links, named pipes, and others. But you are fairly unlikely to have those.

Comment: I forgot about those, which I guess indicates how likely the presence of those are, but doing another type is a simple modification of the given command (but it requires reading the documentation which is a good thing for such dangerous commands. If you want to handle more than one type (or perhaps everything that isn't a directory) at once, the answer is also in the documentation.

Comment: Or `! -type d` in place of `-type f` to delete all non-directories.

Comment: If you want to reduce the risk of running this command from the wrong place and wiping key parts of your file system, you can specify the full path for `find`, as in `find /home/apps/Batches -type f -delete`

Comment: Run it without `-delete` first to get a list of files that will be deleted.